# when setting up a webserver on linux , is it a good practice to make a new user and install everything under that user?

Tags: webserver, users

I want to set up a webserver and I understand that when using linux its not safe to install things under root. So should I install things like apache and php under a different user? And if i do, will everything be installed in the /usr directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Linux you should not **run** things as `root` unless it's essential. This means that most installations will actually be done as `root`, normally by using the `sudo` command (or the GUI equivalent) as this ensures that all the files can be put in the right locations, with most files being below the `/usr` directory.

The Apache developers are well aware of security concerns and, by default, will install the webserver to run as a specially created user; on my system, most of the apache2 instances are running under the user `www-data` which I believe is the default (it's a long time since I installed it).

I think you can override the default locations for the actual web files during installation, but normal practice is to use the default (`/var/www` as I recall) and then link subfolders to there.

In summary, taking the defaults of the installation (run as `root` or using `sudo`) will give you a reasonably safe setup and you don't need to take any special action.